# Input type for array of objects as mutation input messes with optimistic response

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

On the server I built a schema where I used and input type to obtain the ability to pass an array of objects. I've done this in a couple of places but this is by far the most simple one:

```
export default gql`
    input SkillInput{
        skill: String!
    }
    extend type Mutation {
            createSkill(input: [SkillInput]): [Skill]!
    }
    type Skill {
        id: ID!
        skill: String!
        created_at: DateTime!
    }
`;
```

On the frontend, I'm able to execute the mutation with said array of objects just fine. The issue comes when I try to incorporate optimistic response.

This isthe mutation in question:

```
this.$apollo
        .mutate({
          mutation: CREATE_SKILL_MUTATION,
          variables: { input: skillArrOfObj },
          optimisticResponse: {
            __typename: "Mutation",
            createSkill: skillArrOfObj.map(entry => ({
              __typename: "Skill",
              id: -1,
              skill: entry.skill
            }))
          },
          update: (store, { data: { createSkill } }) => {
            const data = store.readQuery({
              query: SKILLS_QUERY
            });
            console.log(createSkill);
            data.skills.push(...createSkill);

            store.writeQuery({
              query: SKILLS_QUERY,
              data
            });
          }
        })
```

I've tried to add to each entry of skillArrOfObj the __typename and id, however the mutation fails.

Another thing to mention is that update runs twice and the log on createSkill yields two different results on update:

First run

```
{__typename: "Skill", id: -1, skillObj: Array(2)}
id: -1
skillObj: (2) [{…}, {…}]
__typename: "Skill"
```

Second run shows an array of just the id and the __typename with no skill attribute

Is there a special __typename needed for arrays? Or something I need to do before running the mutation?

Comment: `createSkill` returns a List, so presumably your optimisticResponse should as well, however it only returns a single object.

Comment: skillArrOfObj is an array of objects though so I'm not exactly sure what you mean? Edit: Oh I think I know what you mean now.

Comment: Okay so I've tried unsuccessfully to get the optimistic response to return an array, I tried defining the typename and id outside and shoving the array instead. As reflected in the original post edit. However, I don't get a response from the server

Comment: Got it. I've edited the optimisticResponse above to what worked for me. You should put your responses as answers! They've been very helpful.